# Setfacl is being ignored in a docker container

Tags: docker, acl, alpine-linux

I have an ssh server where I manage project access using ACL. I have a folder name testsuite.git with this ACL:

```
$ getfacl testsuite.git/
# file: testsuite.git/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:highghlow:rw-
group::---
mask::rw-
other::---
```

This is running in docker:
Guest system: Alpine linux
Docker info:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.10.4
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.17.2
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 23.0.4
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 2806fc1057397dbaeefbea0e4e17bddfbd388f38
 runc version: v1.1.5-0-gf19387a
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
 Kernel Version: 5.4.0-147-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 1.883GiB
 Name: remnux
 ID: 18088f03-7b85-438f-917d-482c491b91af
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

I am logged in as highghlow through ssh and should have permissions to read/write testsuite.git, but I don't

```
$ touch testsuite.git/example
touch: testsuite.git/example: Permission denied
```